# How to set cms block to category in Magento 2 programmatically?

Tags: magento2, category, cms, programmatically

I would like to add CMS block to a category programmatically, how to achieve it?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Comment: Hello teja, as per following solution landing_page is cms block identifier right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add a cms block to the Category page, first, you already have cms static block.

If you want to add CMs block to the category then set have to set cms block identifier to  of category and display mode of category page should be `Static block only` **PAGE** and  `Static block and products`  **PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE**.

**Sample code**

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Test;


class CmsBlock {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    private $categroyFactory;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categroyFactory
    ) {

        $this->categroyFactory = $categroyFactory;
    }

 public function saveCMSBlockToCategory()
    {
     $catId = 10;
        $storeId = null; // You can put your store id  here
        $category = $this->categroyFactory->create();
        if (null !== $storeId) {
            $category->setStoreId($storeId);
        }
        $category->load($catId);
        if($category->getId()){
            $category->setData('landing_page',2);
            $category->setData('display_mode','PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE');
            $category->save();
        }
    }
}
```

### NOte

**Not using Service contact class `\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface` as on save method its has magento bug.**

Bug link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10088

Comment: Where i can add your code, can you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330082/57334 @Amit Bera♦

Comment: landing_page is CMS block right?